# Comments in TikZ datavisualization data specification

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

In TikZ datavisualization data is provided in the `data` command inside the `\datavisualization` command.

Is there any syntax to have comments in the built-in data format `table`?
I can not find anything related to that in the manual. Since I think comments inside data files could be quite useful as meta information, I suppose there should be some way to specify such extra information but I am not able to find a way to do this.

I imagine something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
data {
# comment
x, y
-1.5, 2.25
...
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Edit: This would be especially useful for data in external files as they are on their own and by default only have a file name as additional information to describe the contained data.

Comment: it's just tex so `%` comments

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure if this would work when reading the data from a file, but it does!

Comment: Your example is not showing it from a file, but from an inline environment/

Comment: I added that now to the question. I initially forgot to mention that. Sorry for that.

Comment: it's different as `%` is bound to work in the case shown (unless the package worked hard to stop that)  which is why I commented without testing at all. But whether it works in a file depends on how the package reads files, and could have a completely different answer (although it apparently doesn't) .

Comment: That was pretty much the reason why I posted this question in the first place. Because I didn't know what kind of processing is applied to the files when they are read. I did some tests and it seems to work with normal tex comments.

Comment: Spectacularly bad choice of example then:-)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can just use the normal Tex comments using `%`. This works even if the data is read from an external file.